# I need to create an AFTER UPDATE, INSERT trigger to prevent modifications on a table (MS SQL, Microsoft Azure)

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called flights with the following attributes: flight_id, date, start_time_actual, end_time_actual, rout_id, plane_id

I need to create and AFTER UPDATE, INSERT trigger to prevent the insertion or modification in the date column of dates before 2016 and after 2019.

I created the following trigger but I am not sure how to state the restriction:

```
create trigger DateRestriction
on flights
after insert, update
as
set nocount on
BEGIN

IF EXISTS(SELECT* FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
BEGIN
............
ELSEIF EXISTS (SELECT* FROM inserted) AND EXISTS( SELECT * FROM deleted)
BEGIN
declare @temporalinserted table(
id INT IDENTITY,
flight_id INT,
date date,
start_time_actual time,
end_time_actual time,
route_id INT,
plane_id INT);

declare @temporaldeleted table(
id INT IDENTITY,
flight_id INT,
date date,
start_time_actual time,
end_time_actual time,
route_id INT,
plane_id INT);

INSERT INTO @temporalinserted(flight_id, date, start_time_actual, end_time_actual, route_id, 
plane_id)
SELECT flight_id, date, start_time_actual, end_time_actual, route_id, plane_id
FROM inserted

INSERT INTO @temporaldeleted(flight_id, date, start_time_actual, end_time_actual, route_id, 
plane_id)
SELECT flight_id, date, start_time_actual, end_time_actual, route_id, plane_id
FROM deleted
..........
```

the dots should be where the restriction code should go. Is there other way to write this code? or what do I need to add in order to make it work? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: MS SQL Server is correct. I couldn't find the Microsoft SQL tag

Comment: You need a *before* trigger to prevent modifications, not an AFTER. You can also use [row-level security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: BTW there's no `Microsoft SQL`. The database product is SQL Server. The cloud services offered by Microsoft are Azure SQL and Managed SQL Server

Comment: Why not a simple constraint? Since the dates are all in the past, why would anyone be modifying or inserting historical data in the first place? Smells like a big [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Lastly stop blindly applying this pattern of "saving" rows in a temp table/table variable in order to "do something" with them.

Answer (score 0):

To raise an error in SQL and rollback the transaction (block the insert) you can do something like this:

```
RAISERROR ('Error Message', 
   16, -- Severity (16 is typically user-defined)
   1); -- State (can be any # 0 - 255)
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
RETURN
```

Comment: [RAISERROR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is now discouraged - use THROW instead.